# Is it possible to define only one enum status for several models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have several models; each one with an enum status as:

```
enum status: [:active, :canceled, :normal, :done]
```

But, is it possible to define an unique enum status (like model, e.g.) and use it into the others models?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in first_model.rb, you have:

```
enum status: [:active, :canceled, :normal, :done]
```

then in second_model.rb, just do:

```
enum status: FirstModel.statuses
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this enum in config/intializer/xxxx.rb file. This will available to all models. Or say throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a module on lib folder and then include it in the models you need.